# Azure UpdateDomain configurability

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

Basically my question is: What control do I have over Azure Update Domains?

- Can I **discover** how many update domains my role has?
- Can I **define** how many update domains my role has?
- Can I **define** the update domain of a given instance? (assuming that there are more than 1 instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx) you can setup the number of update domains by setting `upgradeDomainCount` in the service definition file, the default value is 5 and that's used if you don't specify the count.

`RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.UpdateDomain` also returns the update domain index of the current role. The Management Portal also shows the update domain number for each instance. Finally you can use [`GetDeployments` Management API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) that will return the list of instances and the upgrade domain number of each.

You cannot explicitly assign an instance to a domain - the assignment is [done in round-robin fashion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781019.aspx) starting from instance 0 and upwards.